# ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS mismatch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, configuration, metadata

When I export the entire list of stored procedures/functions, I noticed there is a mismatch between `ANSI_NULLS`/`QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` settings.  Some have them on, others off.  I'm not explicitly setting this for the stored procedures or functions, so how does SQL determine whether to define on or off for these settings by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so how does SQL determine whether to define on or off for the ansi nulls by default?

[BOL quotes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229(v=sql.80).aspx) - For stored procedures, SQL Server uses the `SET ANSI_NULLS` setting value from the initial creation time of the stored procedure. Whenever the stored procedure is subsequently executed, the setting of `SET ANSI_NULLS` is restored to its originally used value and takes effect. When invoked inside a stored procedure, the setting of `SET ANSI_NULLS` is not changed.

You can use the `sys.sql_modules` to check  the stored procedure or function uses `uses_ansi_nulls` and `uses_quoted_identifier` settings 1 (ON) or 0 (OFF)

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) as ObjectName, 
       uses_ansi_nulls, 
       uses_quoted_identifier
FROM sys.sql_modules
--WHERE OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) = 'any_sp/function_name_your_Want_to_Check'
ORDER BY object_id
```

Both `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` should be ON so that you dont see any unexpected surprises. Also, in newer versions of SQL Server, this two settings are defaulted to ON.

Comment: "Also, in newer versions of SQL Server" but not necessarily the clients themselves, some of them like `sqlcmd` will default turn this off.